# How to push an object to an array of object using Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I am trying to push an object to a list of objects in vuetify. Im using Vue 3.

This is my html code:

```
  <a to="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add to cart"
    @click.stop.prevent="handleAddToCart(product)">
   <v-icon class="icon-bag2">mdi-medical-bag</v-icon>
  </a>
```

Note: I have used stop.prevent cause the icon is inside a div which is clickable.

This is what I have tried in my click event method:
declared in data: productList = []

```
       handleAddToCart(product) {
        this.productList.push(product)
        console.log('product list', this.productList)
        this.$cookies.set('cart', JSON.stringify(this.productList))
      }
```

I want to save this array in cookies but it keeps replacing object and not pushing the object one after another.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
data() {
  return {
    productList : []
  }
}
...
handleAddToCart(product) {
  this.productList.push(product)
  console.log('product list', productList)
  this.$cookies.set('cart', JSON.stringify(productList))
}
```

Comment: I am not understanding why but same thing happens, just keep replacing the object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because each time you click create a new array `let productList = []`, you need to keep your array reference in the data attribute.

```
export default {
  data: {
    return {
       productList: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleAddToCart(product) {
        this.productList = [...this.productList, product]
        console.log('product list', this.productList)
        this.$cookies.set('cart', JSON.stringify(this.productList))
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but same thing happens.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: @Nina What is the result in the `console`?

Comment: Edited description

Comment: @Nina, I'm not sure why it gives you that error, it should work fine, could you re-produce the issue on a live editor like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-ce53j)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `productList` is a proxy object, You can get the target array from this proxy and then push the new product in it.

You can give a try to this **:**

```
handleAddToCart(product) {
  const proxyArr = new Proxy(this.productList, {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
      return target[prop];
    }
  });

  this.productList = [...proxyArr];
  this.productList.push(product);
  this.$cookies.set('cart', JSON.stringify(this.productList))
}
```

Comment: Thanks but either this doesnt work.